# Is there any other library which can be used to connect MySQL in Ruby?

Tags: mysql, ruby, require, dbi

I am now using

> require 'dbi'

But I am just wondering if there is any other alternative? which is the best one? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're having with what you're using? What motivates you to look for alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

mysql2 is the most used library

https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2

gem install 'mysql2'

Answer (score 0):

There is a mySql gem for ruby.  Here is the page for it - http://rubygems.org/gems/mysql

Answer (score 0):

These are the ones that come to my mind:

- Sequel: http://sequel.rubyforge.org/
- Arel:https://github.com/rails/arel